# class overwrite __init__ default parameter

Tags: python

I import a class `Foo` that has a default parameter `dir` upon which if performs a function `doit`. How can I change the default `dir`? Do I need to inherit this class and then change it, how?

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, dir='xxx'):
    self.bar = doit(dir) # fails because xxx is wrong
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you just provide a different argument when you construct an instance of the class:

```
foo = Foo(dir='something else')
```

btw: [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) is a python built-in and therefore not the best choice as variable name.

if you want the default changed, you can inherit indeed:

```
class MyFoo(Foo):
    def __init__(self, d='somethig else'):
        super().__init__(d=d)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a factory function for `Foo` objects and be done with it:

```
def create_foo():
    return Foo(dir='my correct value goes here')
```

Since you're importing `Foo`, you could go a step further and just shadow `Foo` like this:

```
def Foo():
    import foo
    return foo.Foo(dir='my correct value goes here')
```

Of course you *can* inherit from `Foo`. Be sure to look up how to call the base
class constructors. I find that sooo hard to memorize that I just end up google it. Every. Single. Time.

BTW: Looks like @hiro protagonist already has the calling super figured out.

Comment: if by 'figured out' you mean 'googled' then yes: i have figured it out! like your approach too, by the way...